# Why is the MySQL Server install failing

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I'm trying to install **MySQL 5.7.2** on my **windows** laptop. This laptop was previously used in the company and my boss did a "factory reset" on it for whatever that's worth. I got the MySQL community installer and everything else installed fine but the actual server is not installing. I have the C++ redistributable installed.

The progress number climbs to 88% then drops back down to 50% and then it tells me the install failed and I get the below output. I don't see anything in the output that indicates the error. Hopefully, someone has run into this issue before. I chopped out a big section of the "file" portion to fit under the character limit.

````
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {FB709D10-253F-4362-A1DE-39A896CE5549} 
1: Action 9:31:58: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 9:31:58: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 9:31:58: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 9:31:58: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 9:31:58: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 9:31:58: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 9:31:58: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 9:31:58: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
1: Action 9:31:58: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 9:31:58: SaveTargetDir. 
1: Action 9:31:58: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 9:31:58: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Action 9:31:58: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 9:31:59: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
1: Updating component registration
1: Action 9:32:00: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
1: Action 9:32:00: SchedSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: Action 9:32:00: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
1: Action 9:32:00: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
1: Action 9:32:00: RemoveFiles. Removing files
1: Action 9:32:00: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
1: Action 9:32:00: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Folder: Creating folders
1: Action 9:32:00: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
1: Action 9:32:01: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: Creating shortcuts
1: Action 9:32:01: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: Writing system registry values, Name: , Value: 
1: Action 9:32:01: InstallServices. Installing new services
1: Action 9:32:01: SchedSecureObjects. 
1: Action 9:32:01: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: 
1: Action 9:32:01: RegisterUser. Registering user
1: Action 9:32:01: RegisterProduct. Registering product
1: Registering product
1: Action 9:32:01: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
1: Feature: Publishing Product Features
1: Action 9:32:01: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: Action 9:32:01: InstallFinalize. 
1: Action 9:32:01: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 9:32:01: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\mysql\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\performance_schema\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\test\
1: Action 9:32:01: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: File: innochecksum.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\,  Size: 3988920
1: File: libmecab.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\,  Size: 1839616
1: File: lz4_decompress.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\,  Size: 81336
1: File: my_print_defaults.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\,  Size: 3553208
......
......
......
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\polish\,  Size: 79429
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\portuguese\,  Size: 81673
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\romanian\,  Size: 80423
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\russian\,  Size: 94048
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\serbian\,  Size: 81092
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\slovak\,  Size: 79237
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\spanish\,  Size: 80365
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\swedish\,  Size: 79564
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\ukrainian\,  Size: 88623
1: Action 9:32:06: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: icon.ico
1: Shortcut: Icon.MysqlCmdShell
1: Shortcut: rhj5cnaj|MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client
1: Shortcut: b7npydg0|MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client - Unicode
1: Action 9:32:06: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.7, Name: Location, Value: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.7, Name: Version, Value: 5.7.27
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.7, Name: DataLocation, Value: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.7, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FaceName, Value: Lucida Console
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FontWeight, Value: #400
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.7, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 9:32:06: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 9:32:06: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {FB709D10-253F-4362-A1DE-39A896CE5549} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.7.27' failed.```
````

Comment: What OS are you installing on?  What version of MySQL are you installing?  This looks to be the same as https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88661. Some one else suggested deselecting Product Feature "Server data files" as a workaround (seen at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89226).

Comment: Oh it's on Windows 10. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download and install the server through the web installer and let it fail.
2. Navigate to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache\mysql-5.7.21-winx64.exe . In case Program Data is not showing up in your system, do Unhide folder.If exe is not available then you can download location take from installer logs when you are about to install mysql server ,It shows up at the bottom. Double this exe and install. Select custom install
3. Exclude "Server Data Files" from installation list. Once complete re-run your mysql community installer .
4. Now you will see that Mysql server is installed. Under "Quick Action", click "Reconfigure" .
5. Then setup your mysql and it should be done